# Find extra values after comparing two columns of dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a two dataframes which consists of column

df has column: id1

```
id1 
 1  
 2  
 3
 4
 5 
 6
```

df2 has column: id2

```
id2
 2 
 1
 5
 4
```

as you can see in df1 there are values which are not in df2['id2']
`3,6`

is there any way to find it by doing difference of two dataframe columns
or any other way?

i tried it using

`df2.isin(df1)`

but only getting bool values.

but i want the actual rows

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can solve this but Pandas index objects have a `difference` method that finds all the indexes that are missing from the second index from the calling index.

```
idx1 = pd.Index(df.id1)
idx2 = pd.Index(df.id2)

idx1.difference(idx2).values

array([3, 6])
```

With `isin` you will get the same result with this:

```
df[~df.id1.isin(df2.id2)]
```

Comment: The latter example was the one I needed, and pretty straight forward. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could also use set operations

```
list(set(df.id1) - set(df2.id2))

[3, 6]
```